# 'Remove widget' option unavailable for Flutter using 'Alt+Enter' shortcut in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am very used to using the 'Alt+Enter' on a widget to modify it, more often to wrap something around it or removing it in Android Studio. However, today I noticed there is no 'remove widget' option. The rest of the options are still available. Is it the same for everyone? ( previously once I think it got removed).
I am using Flutter stable version 2.0.5 , Dart version 2.12.3 and Android Studio 4.1.3.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is still available , but sometimes android studio can't figure out the child in complex widget,

try it in simple container with child .. and it should appear.

Comment: if that solved your question , mark the question as answered